# Should I put UT test for React Component to the same file with that component?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, mocha.js, separation-of-concerns

Because it's become a commonly used pattern to put markups, styling and javascript of 1 specific React component into 1 single file. Is it also a good pattern to put the unit tests (for example mocha `describe`s) to that same file?

Note: Let's assume the bundle tool can strip unused `import`s and the codes inside `describe`s.

Example:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import { expect } from 'chai';

const MyComponent = ({ active }) => (
  <div style={{ color: active ? 'blue' : 'gray' }}>
    {active ? 'this is active' : 'this is inactive'}  
  </div>
);

export default MyComponent;

// mocha tests (same file)

describe('MyComponent', () => {
  context('active = true', () => {
    it('should include is active text', () => { ... });
    it('should have color blue', () => { ... });
  });

  context('active = false', () => { ... });
});
```

Comment: this would bundle your tests with your production build...?

Comment: This is probably **not** a good practice. This will needlessly bloat the code that runs in prod.  Better, to separate tests into another file and exclude them from the bundle.

Comment: Let's assume the bundle tool can strip the unused imports and describes from production build

Answer (score 0):

This would bind you and will lead to many problems. I do not know much about your architecture. But in this way you are not allowed to use any analyze tool. If you will be using any tool to test your Code Climate for example SonarQube it will be parsing also test and it fails.

Another scenario: Let's assume that you are running necessary builds when you are pushing to the repository. Your app is growing and you need to run SonarQube within each pull. You need to add a heuristic check if your pull is touching `*.spec.js` files -> again you can not.

This is also not used and not best practice. The most used and most common practice is to put your spec to the file with the same name and postfix `spec.js` or to the different folder within the root of component like `__spec__/component.js`.

Your approach will not help to anything at all and you can not separate pure code from tests in any scenario which is very bad.